# Magento 2.3: Error Creating Order Programmatically

Tags: php, magento2.3, create-order

I'm trying to create an order programmatically using the following code in a cron script:

```
$order = [
          'currency_id' => 'USD',
          'email' => 'test@test.com',
          'shipping_address' => [
            'firstname' => 'John',
            'lastname' => 'Doe',
            'street' => 'Test Main St.',
            'city' => 'Tulsa',
            'country_id' => 'US',
            'region' => 'OK',
            'postcode' => '74146',
            'telephone' => '+1 555-444-3333',
            'save_in_address_book' => 1],
            'items' => [
              ['product_id' => '1', 'qty' => 1]
            ]
          ];

          $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
          $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
          $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
          $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
          $customer->loadByEmail($order['email']); // load customet by email address
          if (!$customer->getEntityId()) {
            //If not avilable then create this customer
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->setStore($store)->setFirstname($order['shipping_address']['firstname'])->setLastname($order['shipping_address']['lastname'])->setEmail($order['email'])->setPassword($order['email']);
            $customer->save();
          }
          $quote = $this->quote->create(); // Create Quote Object
          $quote->setStore($store); // Set Store
          $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
          $quote->setCurrency();
          $quote->assignCustomer($customer); // Assign quote to Customer

          //add items in quote
          foreach ($order['items'] as $item) {
            $product = $this->product->load($item['product_id']);
            $product->setPrice(99.99);
            $quote->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));
          }

          $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($order['shipping_address']);
          $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($order['shipping_address']);

          // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
          $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
          $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
          $quote->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery');
          $quote->save();

          // Set Sales Order Payment
          $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'cashondelivery']);

          // Collect Totals & Save Quote
          $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();

          // Create Order From Quote
          $orderdata = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);

          $orderdata->setEmailSent(0);
          $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
          if ($orderdata->getEntityId()) {
            $result['order_id'] = $orderdata->getRealOrderId();
          } else {
            $result = ['error' => 1, 'msg' => 'Your custom message'];
          }
          return $result;
```

But receiving the following error:

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException] The shipping method
>   is missing. Select the shipping method and try again.

The flatrate shipping method that is being called is enabled. Any ideas?

Comment: Please see my solution here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/320495/15474 You need to use this model `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate`

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I do it via console in my script I put together

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Faker/blob/master/Helper/Order.php#L109-L192

```
    public function createOrder($storeId = 1)
    {

        // bypass Area code not set
        $this->_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $this->cartManagementInterface = $this->_objectManager->create(CartManagementInterface::class);

        try {
            $store = $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore($storeId);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);

            return;
        }

        $websiteId = $store->getWebsiteId();
        $customerIds = $this->getRandomCustomerId($websiteId);
        if (empty($customerIds)) {
            new \Exception(__('Please add some customers for this store first'));
        }

        $customer = $this->getCustomerById($customerIds[0]);
        if (!$customer) {
            new \Exception(__('Problem loading customer'));
        }

        $cartId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart(); //Create empty cart
        $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId); // load empty cart quote
        $quote->setStore($store);
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer);

        $productIds = $this->getRandomProductId(rand(1, 10));

        if (empty($productIds)) {
            new \Exception(__('Please add some produts for this store first'));
        }

        foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
            $product = $this->getProductById($productId);
            $product->setStore($store);
            $product->setPrice($this->faker->randomFloat(4, 0, 100));
            $quote->addProduct($product, (int) (rand(1, 2)));
        }

        $billingAddress = $this->addressFactory->create()->load($customer->getDefaultBilling());
        $shippingAddress = $this->addressFactory->create()->load($customer->getDefaultShipping());

        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($billingAddress->getData());
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($shippingAddress->getData());

        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');

        $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);

        $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);

        try {
            $this->cartRepositoryInterface->save($quote);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);

            return;
        }

        $quote->collectTotals();
        $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($quote->getId());

        try {
            $orderId = $this->cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($quote->getId());
            $this->generateInvoice($orderId);
            if ($this->getRandomTrueOrFalse()) {
                $this->generateShipment($orderId);
            }

            return $orderId;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        }
    }
```